# emacs fsharp-mode: Cached typecheck results not yet available

Tags: emacs, f#

I'm unable to get [fsharp-mode](https://github.com/fsharp/emacs-fsharp-mode) to display the type signatures. I turned on the debug output and there's the following message: 'Cached typecheck results not yet available'. Any ideas how to get it working?